# How to select checkbox using localStorage value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dropdown

I am using Checkboxes the value is consider a Dropdown box.

```
<div class="form-group" id="permission">
    <label> Permission : </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="permission" id="pRead" value="pread" > Read 
    <input type="checkbox" name="permission" id="pWrite" value="pwrite"> Write 
    <input type="checkbox" name="permission" id="pDelete" value="pdelete" > Delete 
<div>
```

Comment: please provide more information. Please provide some code you have tried yourself.

Comment: Do you have any problems with code you've written? If so, please show that code. If your question is 'how do I programmatically check a checkbox' then there's thousands of answers to that already if you take the time to search.

Comment: I don't find any question~

Comment: @kit Take a look at the title.

Comment: So that's mean he want us to suggest a solution for him?

Comment: @kit "Welcome to SO" this is what you see, and this is what you get ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('input[name="permission"][value="' + value + '"]:checkbox"').prop('checked',true);
```

"value" will be your local storage value